# Plesk 12 trying to get a mail with queue details

Tags: linux, email, plesk

I'm trying to set up a mail which will tell me when there is 100 mails in the mail queue.  I'm not a linux server person so i@d appreciate some help.  I have:

```
            # get server hostname
            hostname=`cat /etc/hostname`

            current_mailq= "/var/qmail/bin/qmail-qstat"

            # `postqueue -p | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f5`

            yourEmail="xxxx@gmail.com"


            if [ "$current_mailq" -gt "100" ]
            then
            echo "Mail queue problem - there is currently $current_mailq mails in queue. Please check it out." > check_email_queue_outgoing.txt
            mail -s "$hostname - mail queue alert - there are $current_mailq emails in queue" "$yourEmail" < check_email_queue_outgoing.txt
            else
            echo "Mail queue is fine - there is currently $current_mailq mails in queue. Please check it out."
            echo "Do nothing, situation is fine."
            fi
```

Which I found on a plesk forum.

When I run the cron job it says

```
        Output from command /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh ..

        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 2: 
        : command not found
        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 3: 
        : command not found
        cat: /etc/hostname: No such file or directory
        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 6: 
        : command not found
        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 7: /var/qmail/bin/qmail-qstat
        : No such file or directory
        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 8: 
        : command not found
        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 10: 
        : command not found
        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 12: 
        : command not found
        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 13: 
        : command not found
        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
        /home/xxxxxx/check_email_queue.sh: line 21: `fi'
        Mail handler 'limit-out' said: REPLY:554:5.7.0 Your message could not be sent. The user xxxxxx is not allowed to send email.
```

Any ideas please?

edit ...

I switched the user to root and it now sends mail but the other errors remain - I can't find out the size of the mail queue
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname=`cat /etc/hostname`

current_mailq="`postqueue -p | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f5`"
yourEmail="xxxx@gmail.com"

echo "$current_mailq"

if (( "$current_mailq" >= "100" )) ; then
echo "Mail queue problem - there is currently $current_mailq mails in queue. Please check it out." > check_email_queue_outgoing.txt
mail -s "$hostname - mail queue alert - there are $current_mailq emails in queue" "$yourEmail" < check_email_queue_outgoing.txt
else
echo "Mail queue is fine - there is currently $current_mailq mails in queue. Please check it out."
echo "Do nothing, situation is fine."
fi
```

Pay attention it's really hard to make good portable bash/sh/cmd code. IMO, it's better to take [Go language](https://golang.org/) and create clear portable programs for any OS.